# comvisible c# dll , needs to be updated

Tags: c#, com, comvisible

I am going nuts over why a com dll does not get updated on a target server .

I had a DLL that worked before , now the code been updated and new functions been added.

( My dll is a .net v4 (x86)  )

I did a regasm /codebase /register /tlb *.dll and a gacutil /i .

Per my client program the new functions become  are visible but I get DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME upon calling them .

So how this could be possible ? 
What am I to do ?

tx,
Gabor

Comment: Without any concrete details, all we can do is offer you moral support.

Comment: Do *not* use gacutil when you register with /codebase.  Remove any copies you may have in the GAC so the client program cannot load an old version.

Comment: Hi Hans, you are likely to be true as sometimes i have seen odd cases when only the old outdated interface is visible..

Comment: What? `*.dll` when calling `regasm`? Does that even work?